# React seems to be rendering all elements but only displaying the first?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, render

I have a component:

```
const StudentName = (student) => (
    <div key={student.engName} test={console.log("Name: "+student.val().engName)}>
        <Typography
            className={ student==currentStudent ? 'selectedStudentName' : 'unselectedStudentName' }>
                {student ? student.engName : null}'s Homework</Typography>
    </div>
)
```

which I render with:

```
return ( 
    <div>
        { students ? students.map((student) => StudentName(student)) : null}
    </div>
);
```

'students' is held in useState, so the app should be rendering on every update (students are retrieved from firebase and added)

I'm testing it with an array of 3 students. I can see that both of them are making StudentName elements as I get the output:

```
//Name: David
//Name: Michelle
//Name: Sunny
```

However, only a single StudentName element for David is displayed. When I inspect elements on my page, that is the only one there too. BUT in my app I click another page then click back, all three StudentNames are displayed. Just not initially. This makes no sense to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try returning the StudentName in map `{ students ? students.map((student) => return StudentName(student)) : null}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return ( 
    <div>
        { students && students.map((student, indx) => <React.Fragment key={indx}> 
                 {StudentName(student)}
        </React.Fragment> })
    </div>
);
```